# Not able to publish Cucumber report in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: html, azure, cucumber

Getting below error in pipeline

(Artifact name input: Test Run Report ##[error]Path does not exist: D:\a\1\s\cypress\reports)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are facing the issue while in Publishing artifact by using in different tasks.

**Please follow the steps to fix the issue**

you can download artifacts from earlier stages in your pipeline or from another pipeline. You can also publish your artifact to a file share or make it available as a pipeline artifact.

steps:

```
- publish:  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp
    artifact:  WebApptest
```

If you trying to consume the artifact from a job running on a different OS, you must ensure all the file paths are valid for the target environment. For example, a file name containing the character `\` or `*` will fail to download on Windows.

The path of the file/folder to you want to publish is required. This can be an absolute or a relative path to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`.

Download artifacts

```
steps:
    - download:  current
    artifact:  WebApptest
```

Refer here [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285774/publish-build-artifact-task-results-path-does-not-exist-error) & [Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)